# How to compile Fluidsynth for android jni

Tags: c, audio, compilation, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've been having problems on compiling Fluidsynth (1.0.9) for Android JNI. 
After reading into the steps at: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8201#c38
I'm still stuck with allowing the android JNI access and use any Fluidsynth method.

I created a separate fluidsynth folder inside the jni/ folder of the Android project and created an Android.mk file inside the fluidsynth folder, where the Android.mk includes all .c files in the fluidsynth src folder.

Am I missing something? How about some linker for the header files..?

I've tried using Fluidsynth method for instantiating a fluidsynth_setting and when I used ndk-build it has this output:

> It outputs an error on ndk-build: " undefined reference to
>   `new_fluid_settings' .. "

Any help on how to compile c libraries/projects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out that Android.mk is a bit tricky.

Removed all the commented lines (eery line with "#" at the start) and then some of the .c files were compiling (producing "Compile thumb <= filename.c" after executing ndk-build).

After fixing bugs (undeclared variables, adding missing libraries), fluidsynth finally compiled.

Answer (score 0):

new_fluid_settings symbol is defined in src\utils\fluid_settings.c file. Are you sure you are including it into your Android.mk file?